# How does a node discover new peers?

Tags: node, network

How does a node that joins the network for the first time connect to peers? Are there some hardcoded peers and does it use DNS (as other cryptocurrencies)?
And then, how does a node learns about new peers?

Answer (score 1):

On the EOS Mainnet, new peers need to be manually added.  See https://validate.eosnation.io/mainnet/reports/config.txt for an up-to-date and validated list.